# What are the rules for spaces in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spaces, ruby-1.9.2

```
a = [2,4,5]
a.count-1 => 2
a.count - 1 => 2
```

But

```
a.count -1 => 0
```

What causes this behavior? Why doesn't it happen if a is an integer (and not an array)?

Also, I have noticed that there must not be a space between a method name and the parenthesis that follows (for parameters). Why is that?

Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because methods can be called with no parentheses, this:

```
a.count - 1
```

Means subtract 1 from `a.count`, whereas

```
a.count -1 # is like a.count(-1)
```

Means call the method `a.count` with `-1` as an argument. It doesn't happen when `a` is an integer because integers don't have the `count` method. You just have to be careful as you type.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that in the case of `a.count -1`, `-` is still a method. See here: http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html

Answer (score 1):

```
a.count - 1 # you are subtracting 
a.count -1  # you are doing a.count(-1)
```

Are you sure you can't put a space between a method name and the parens? I just did it in ruby 1.9.2 and it works fine. For example

```
a.product([3])
a.product ([3])
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.count -1` is equivalent to `a.count(-1)`.

It returns the number of times -1 is included in your array.

```
a = [-1, 3, 4]
a.count -1 => 1
```